# Gradle Copy Contents of Multiple Directories Into One

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have one build directory which needs to receive config files from two source directories X and Y during a Gradle build.

So I have two different gradle tasks, one that copies from X to build and one that copies from Y to build. These are standard (type: Copy) **from** source **into** destination tasks.

However, instead of my build directory getting populated with the union of all files/folders in X and Y, it just ends up with the files from one of them, as if one overwrote the other.

Am I correct in concluding that overwriting is standard behavior for the Gradle copy function?

And if so, how can I structure my build script so I can combine these two directories into one?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself - basically if you're copying an entire directory into your target directory and then copying an identically-named directory from somewhere else into that same place, then Gradle can't merge them and so one overwrites the other.

The solution to this is to make your copy task more specific so it copies at the file level rather than at the folder level.

It's possible there may be a more programmatic way of getting it to actually merge the folders, if anyone has that feel free to add it on.